# How to Force Normal Logging for a React Native App that Loads Multiple Times?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a react app with a codebase I inherited.

In this component file: **index.jsx** I have this import:

```
import { CLicksAverage } from '../../Components/Averages';
```

And further down in the **index.jsx** file I have this bit:

```
} else if (attribute === 'Clicks') {
        chart = <ClicksAverage />;
```

"CLicksAverage" is a references to **clicks.jsx** (does not extend component) which has this structure:

```
 const ClicksAverage = ({ type }) => {

    if (type === 'Daily' || type === 'Today') {

      console.log('Daily or Today');   

    } else if (type === 'Weekly' || type === 'Monthly') {

        if (type === 'Weekly') {

        console.log('Weekly');   

        } else {

        console.log('Monthly');       

        }

    } else if (type === 'Yearly') {

        console.log('Monthly');

    }

}
```

**THE PURPOSE**
I am logging events. In this case a "weekly", "monthly" and "yearly" tab click. When the page loads, the default is "weekly".

**THE PROBLEM**
The react app hits ClicksAverage three times on the initial load. Accordingly, it logs:

```
   > Weekly
   > Weekly
   > Weekly
```

After that initial load, it behaves as normal and each click lines up to a unique instance of what is being logged. For example:

```
> Yearly
> Weekly
> Monthly
> Yearly
> Yearly
> etc...
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
I need to force the initial load to log Weekly only once (or not at all). And then allow the user to click on the weekly tab as normal and log that event. What I have in place feels like a kluge - there must be a better way.

For when the weekly tab is clicked, I do this:

```
 if (type === 'Weekly') {

        trackWeeklyClicksTab();  

   } else {
```

And in trackWeeklyClicks I have a local variable loadCount that is initialized to zero in a static class. This accounts for the three loads of ClicksAverage. But I don't like it. The code should work regardless of the load count. In this scenario I also have the problem of blowing away the logging for weekly clicks (It only logs once).

```
  trackWeeklyClicksTab() {
    if (this.loadCount < 3) {
      this.weeklyClicksRunOnce();
      this.loadCount += 1;
    } else {
      console.log('Weekly Clicks Tab');
    }
  }

  weeklyClicksRunOnce() {
    console.log('Weekly Clicks Tab');
    this.weeklyClicksRunOnce = () => {};
  }
```

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `useEffect` hook? This should log `type` when ever the value changes.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(type)
}, [type])
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. I am new to react and didn't find that one in the documentation. Super useful, thank you.

Comment: @Peter hooks are a relatively new feature to React. You can find the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). We've largely moved to using function components with hooks over class components. I'd strongly suggest doing a tutorial on hooks.